# Setup Play ScalaJS project for Client-side JS

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala.js

Most of the ScalaJS examples around show server-side usage of ScalaJS combined with client-side.  There are a lot of plugins and SBT options and Play Framwork quirks - to say the least this is all quite confusing.

How do I setup a Play project so that ScalaJS will compile to JS on the server, be callable from a Scala file (scalatags) but only be executed by the client.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What is wrong with this example: https://github.com/vmunier/play-with-scalajs-example ? What do you mean by "Scala.js will compile to JS on the server"? Scala.js is compiled to JS as part of your build step, just like your Play project is compiled to .class files as part of your build step.

Comment: @sjrd The example provides for more than what I need, and I am having trouble teasing apart the concerns.  "Scala.js is compiled to JS as part of your build step" This is mainly what I am looking for - how can I do just this?

Comment: "This is mainly what I am looking for - how can I do just this?" If that's what you're looking for, just don't look at integrations with any framework. The basic Scala.js tutorial covers that. http://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial.html Then you have one .js file, and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @sjrd The problem arises when using it as in the ScalaJS examples with the Play framework.  It says something about not being able to run on the same thread, which is strange if the JS is being compiled at program compile rather than at runtime.